# How to create box plot displaying mean and standard deviation and a scatterplot of points as well

Tags: r, matlab, stata, scatter-plot, boxplot

I am attempting to create a box plot displaying mean and standard deviation and a scatterplot of points in the software R by modifying the code below.

```
library(ggplot2)

# create fictitious data
a <- runif(10)
b <- runif(12)
c <- runif(7)
d <- runif(15)

# data groups
group <- factor(rep(1:4, c(10, 12, 7, 15)))

# dataframe
mydata <- data.frame(c(a,b,c,d), group)
names(mydata) <- c("value", "group")

# function for computing mean, DS, max and min values
min.mean.sd.max <- function(x) {
  r <- c(min(x), mean(x) - sd(x), mean(x), mean(x) + sd(x), max(x))
  names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  r
}

# ggplot code
p1 <- ggplot(aes(y = value, x = factor(group)), data = mydata)
p1 <- p1 + stat_summary(fun.data = min.mean.sd.max, geom = "boxplot") + geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.2), size=3) + ggtitle("Boxplot con 
   media, 95%CI, valore min. e max.") + xlab("Gruppi") + ylab("Valori")
```

This is my dataset:

```
number  name    percent
1   CD1_lung1   0.824214533
3   CD1_lung2   1.118706494
5   CD1_lung3   1.271139637
7   CD1_lung4   0.785939335
9   CNR_20  0.592576592
11  CNR_lung    1.764129689
13  CNR_2   0.643293719
2   Gpc_KO1_lung    0.730014957
4   Gpc_KO2_lung    0.679556429
6   Gpc_KO3_lung    1.00910329
8   KO12    1.074708817
10  Gpc1_hom_lung   1.86280637
12  KO35    0.521546931
14  KO45    0.486304707
```

I loaded it into R using read.table("C:/Users/me/Desktop/WB0823_m1/wb0823R.txt", header = TRUE); however, I'm stuck on what to do next since I'm very new to using R. If there's an easier way to create this boxplot in MATLAB or Stata instead, I'd like to know too please! I was not able to figure it out for either of those two softwares either.

Comment: Even in R it would help to know what you want other than what the code does already. You say you want to modify the code: add what? remove what? change what? Traditionally a box plot is based on a box showing median and quartiles although there are many variations on what else is shown.  For Stata and MATLAB I think you are asking for code to draw a graph you don't fully explain or even exemplify, or else you're assuming perfect bilingual fluency. .

Comment: Further, what is the relationship between the problem and your final dataset? On the face of it you have 14 names and one measurement each, so the only scope for calculating mean and SD is to lump them all together.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know what's the goal of your analysis and what your data mean. Do you have replicates in your data / which are the groups? Are those values your raw data or some sort of aggregates? It is totally unclear from your post.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I'm trying to create a boxplot that looks something like the graph at this link: http://statistic-on-air.blogspot.com/2014/02/boxplot-with-mean-and-standard.html

Comment: Basically I want to create a boxplot displaying the mean, the mean + sd, and mean -sd, and plot my data points on top on the box plot if that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for linking to the thread. It contains this comment by one Bernhard "Have you also considered changing the value of pi to 2.0 and renaming the mean as "the Oxford-Meier-Blubb"? Please, don't do any of these three. There are enough recipients struggeling with the meaning of a boxplot. If there finally are boxplot-like-figures that are not boxplots, it's going to hurt. Please find an alternative way to display the results." Seems spot on to me.

Comment: Stata has as a built-in command `dotplot` which allows a plot of all data points together with a bar showing mean +/- SD.

Comment: I tried to use to dotplot command in Stata, but how do I get it to display the bar showing the mean +/- SD?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to read the data into R and decide which individuals to group, then the rest of the code should work. To edit the plot, ggplot2 has a helpful website: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ . This should get you started:

```
library(ggplot2)

#read data into R (I just pasted your data into a blank text file)
mydata <- read.table("~/Desktop/tmp.txt",header=T) 

#add a column to group observations (I guessed here)
mydata$group <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,4,4)

# function for computing mean, DS, max and min values
min.mean.sd.max <- function(x) {
  r <- c(min(x), mean(x) - sd(x), mean(x), mean(x) + sd(x), max(x))
  names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  r
}

# ggplot code 
ggplot(aes(y = percent, x = factor(group)), data = mydata)+
  ggtitle("Boxplot con media, 95%CI, valore min. e max.")+xlab("Gruppi")+ylab("Valori")+
  stat_summary(fun.data = min.mean.sd.max, geom = "boxplot")+
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.2), size=3)
```

Comment: Thank you! For grouping, since my first 7 values are control values and the last 7 values are also grouped together, would it make sense to change the line to mydata$group <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2) ?

Comment: yup that will give you two groups to plot.